# What size anode do I need for this tank

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, hot-water, anode

I have an old pressurized hot water cylinder and I am trying to change the sacrificial anode however the local plumbing stores seem to only have anodes for models they currently sell and also I'm unsure how to work out what I need - for all I know one from a different brand may work but I don't know how to express the measurement. 
I removed the anode from the tank and measured the diameter **across the threads**. It came to 41.25 mm ( not sure how to express that in inches ) ... but I don't know if this is the correct thing to measure - some stuff I've read even seem to suggest going by the size of the hex head which doesn't make much sense to me.

How would find what "size" I'm looking for and is there any such thing as a generic  anode or something standardized that would fit this tank, even with some kind of adapter. I spent a long time trying to get the original manufactured ACV to tell me anything useful and I feel I've exhausted everything I can on that front, including talking to their local suppliers
Any help no matter how sparse would be welcomed, thanks. There are already signs of rust and if I dont get a new anode in the tank it will be lost no doubt

I also wondered about the last resort idea of just dumping bits of magnesium via the anode opening into the bottom of the tank - would this not achieve the same result - I know I wouldn't be able to see if the anode needed replacement but at least I'd get an anode in the tank

Anode goes in from the side - it's a 300 litre ACV tank aprox 6' by 3'

**Tank Details**
- 500litre pressurised cylinder
- model number is B 50 DSF/E
- year: 2004

[image: tank image]

**Here are some images of the anode**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a make/model # of the tank?

Comment: Yes I'll just add it sorry

Comment: How about pictures of the old anode rod, of the whole thing and a close-up of the threaded end?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it good point ... I've added them above

Comment: I'm really just trying to find out how to take a measurement of it ... surely there's some standard sizes or something ... does anybody know how to measure it?